# Querying a table for rows with no foreign keys pointing to them

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's say we have two tables in our database.

Table 1:

```
Employer:
    id
    name
```

Table 2:

```
Employee:
    id
    name
    employer_id
```

My goal is to find a relatively efficient query to find **all employers with no employees**.  The only way I could think to do this involves a subquery, but I suspect there should be a way to do this using a JOIN.

Here's what I originally had:

```
SELECT * FROM employer
    WHERE employer.id NOT IN (
         SELECT employer_id FROM employee
    );
```

As I couldn't find any answers online for this, my solution is in the answers below (admittedly with a good chunk of help from a coworker).  I'm using postgres 9.3 and sqlalchemy 0.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM employer 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employee ON employee.employer_id = employer.id 
    WHERE employee.id IS NULL;
```

For those not familiar with outer joins (I wasn't before this), this query will return all employer/employee pairs AND returns all employers without employees.  These will be paired up with "dummy" employee rows, with all values being NULL.  As a consequence, filtering out all results with employee ids will leave you with just the employers without employees.

(If anyone can give a better-worded explanation, by all means please do.)

In sqlalchemy:

```
session.query(Employer).outerjoin(
    Employer.id==Employee.employer_id
    ).filter(Employee.id==None)
```

Comment: This kind of join, where you do a left outer join and find only non-matching rows, is called a *left anti-join*.